# Maven Surefire Not Running Tests in Suite - Tests Detected as Zero

Tags: java, maven, playwright, maven-surefire-plugin, playwright-java

I am experiencing an issue with Maven's Surefire plugin in my test automation project. When I run individual test classes using mvn test -Dtest=TestClass, it works fine. However, executing my test suite using mvn test -Dtest=TestSuite results in no tests being recognized. The output consistently shows "Tests run: 0", indicating that no tests are executed. Additionally, when running tests from the suite class, I get the message "No tests were found."

I'm seeking assistance to understand why my test suite isn't being recognized by Maven Surefire and how to resolve this issue. Any insights or suggestions on the cause of this behavior and potential fixes would be greatly appreciated.

**CODE:**

Here's my pom.xml:
https://pastebin.com/QXVpd9CN

Here's an example of a base test class (BaseTest.java): https://pastebin.com/ihtNkxHp

And an example of a specific test class (Application1BaseTest.java): https://pastebin.com/WU3fj4Qv
Finally, my suite class (SmokeTests.java):https://pastebin.com/Av9z1PkG

### Here's what I've tried and observed so far:

1. **Test Structure**: My tests are located in **src/main/java**, which is unconventional but intentional for this project.
2. **Test Annotations**: I've ensured that my test methods are properly annotated with **`@Test`** from **org.junit.jupiter.api.Test**.
3. **POM Configuration**: In **pom.xml**, I've set the **<testSourceDirectory>** to **src/main/java**. Additionally, I've checked the Surefire plugin configuration to make sure it includes my test classes and patterns.
4. **Suite Configuration**: I created a test suite class with **@Suite** and **@SelectClasses** annotations from JUnit Jupiter to aggregate my tests. However, running this suite with Maven results in no tests being executed.
5. **Classpath Issues**: I'm suspecting there might be a classpath issue, although running tests individually works fine.
6. **JUnit 5 Dependencies**: I've made sure to include all necessary JUnit 5 dependencies in my **pom.xml**.

EDIT:
I've actually tried conventional approach. I've placed all tests in src/main/java/test as well as BaseTest. Suite still can't find any tests. When running mvn test - test files are found, when running mvn test with only Suite enabled I'm getting 0 tests run.
I've uploaded new pom.xml - note that I've already tried using build-helper-maven-plugin

Comment: You have to have junit-suite-engine as a dependency also why changing the test directory does not make sense... the includes can be removed because those are the defaults...also recommend to use `<maven.compiler.release>21</maven.compiler.release>` instead of source/target as properties as well as configuration in the plugin...

Comment: I am building test automation project, so I won't have any application code. That is why I decided to skip src/main/test and place all files in src/main/java.
I have a structure like that: applications>app1>pages|tests
I keep locators with pages and use methods from page class in test class
Is it a bad practice? How to keep it clean and maintainable?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [add-test-source](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-test-source-mojo.html) goal from [Build Helper](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) plugin, to add `src/main/java` as a test source as follows:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>add-test-source</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <sources>
          <source>src/main/java</source>
        </sources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

And ensure you have the `scope` correct on the JUnit Jupiter dependencies; `scope` should not be set or set to `compile`.

It's also worth noting, this is a little weird. If you're putting tests in `src/main/java` because you want to get them into a JAR for reuse, then [Maven has a convention for test JARs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html).

Comment: This solution didn't helped in my case. Maybe the issue is kinda connected with structure. I will try more conventional approach, but I am wondering why tests should be placed in test directory?
Maven do recognize them it just doesn't work with suites.

Comment: That's weird, I tried it with a test project (without setting `testSourceDirectory`) and it worked fine for me.  Maven is all about conventions, `src/test/java` being one of them.  As a rule of thumb, depart from those conventions at your peril.

Comment: I've changed my approach as you've suggested. Now I do have src/main/java/test and there I keep all test files with BaseTest and all extending AppBaseTest classes. Maven catches all Test classes when run with mvn test but suite is not recognized even with added specific include <include>**/*Suite.java</include>.

Comment: I must admit, I'm not that familiar with the JUnit Platform Suite API, but looking at the docs (https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/index.html#junit-platform-suite-engine) they say you need a dependency on a suite engine, which seems to be missing from your pom.